# php mysql relational definition in tables

Tags: php, mysql

guys I've been trying to create create a school results management system.There is a `STUDENT` table and many `COURSE` tables. Each student **must** be linked to **all** Courses tables. e.g `JOHN, MARY,PETER` must partake in `MATHEMATICS, ENGLISH, ELECTROPHYSICS, PROGRAMMING` etc
My problem is how to define this relationship in mysql and at same time let these students fetch only their own results in all the courses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a requirement to have each course in a separate COURSE table but that doesn't make much sense. You should have a STUDENT table and a COURSES table. Then, you will need a STUDENT_COURSES table to show which courses a student has taken or must take. Your table structure should be something like:

- STUDENT: Id, Name, Gender, etc
- STUDENT_COURSES: Id, Student_Id, Course_Id, Taken, Grade
- COURSES: Id, Course_Name

When a new student is created, you would need to add records to the STUDENT_COURSES table to insert the new STUDENT.Id into the Student_Id field and the Course_Id for each of the required courses. The default value for Taken would be false and the Grade would be Null or Empty String.

This is a very simplistic example and would not work in a real world solution because you would need to have Instructors, Locations, Etc. to make anything useful. But hopefully this will help you get started.